# Are there known manufacturing issues with 1x1 gold cones?

Tags: replacement-parts, quality

Are there any known issues with LEGO 1x1 gold cones?  We received a set containing them and two broke within an hour (under normal use).

They were part of this set.  You can see one on the top of the locomotive and house.  Anyone have positive (or negative) experiences with Lego on sending out replacement parts?

[image]

Comment: I have dozens and dozens of broken pieces that are dark reddish brown (from different sets) - 1x1-s, 1x4-s, etc. I have a dedicated container where I collect these - every single one of them broke on first use. Haven't yet seen issues with gold yet but some colors seem to be extremely poorly manufactured (dark reddish brown, light blue, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unknown what could have caused your issue. LEGO does change plastic and coloring formula from time to time. While rare this still may result in customers having similar issues with bricks sometimes.

Please get in touch with [LEGO Customer Service](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service) and they will be more than happy to help with your issue and take a note of what went wrong to address the global problem (if there is one).

Comment: Did this, and they were happy to send replacement pieces.